# Cloudinary error on joining a video and an Image

Tags: python, cloudinary

We want to show an image before rendering the full video. This is our code

````
cloudinary.uploader.upload_large(
https://res.cloudinary.com/ama-fans/video/upload/v1645395910/temptemp1.mp4,
     transformation=[
       {'height': 200, 'width': 300, 'crop': "fill"},
       {'flags': "splice", 'overlay': {'url': "https://hcti.io/v1/image/7a19364a-4a5b-4bc1-9ee8-cb7dea1fc06f",
                                                      "resource_type": "fetch",
                                                      'type': 'upload'}, "duration": 3},
       {'height': 200, 'width': 300, 'crop': "fill"},
       {'flags': "layer_apply", 'start_offset': "0"}
       ],
    format='mp4',
    resource_type = "video",
    chunk_size = 6000000,
    public_id = "sample_id",
    api_key="",
    api_secret="",
    cloud_name="ama-fans"
    )
    ```
    
The resulting video is really weird though it has both the image and the video. The resulting video is very short and has blurred voice.
http://res.cloudinary.com/ama-fans/video/upload/v1645457716/sample_id.mp4
````

Comment: You can try doing the video splicing and image overlay as shown in this [link](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4404163979794-Video-conatination-and-adding-watermark-overlay?page=1#:~:text=videos%20and%20overlay%20image).

Comment: So we tried, Everything was working except when the videos are recorded for macosx devices.